# Вставка через шаблонные строки

Tags: javascript, css, html5

есть у меня функция render() в котором я создаю блок

```
const mainBlock = document.createElement('div');
mainBlock.classList = 'aboutMe';
mainBlock.innerHTML =`
            <div class="aboutMe__info">
                <p class="aboutMe__text">${generalIfo}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="aboutMe__cont>
                <p class="aboutMe__phone">${phone}</p>
                <p class="aboutMe__mail">${mail}</p>
            </div>
        `;
```

и есть функция

```
function renderABC(){

    const abc = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c'
    }

    let a = document.createElement('div');
    a.className = 'asd';

    for (let key in abc) {
        a.innerHTML += `<div>${abc[key]}</div>`
    }

    return a;
}
```

возможно ли вставить созданный функцией блок с данными с объекта, с помощью шаблонной строки, так как при попытке вставить таким образом ${renderABC()} выдает object HTMLDivElement

или мне лучше просто сделать так mainBlock.append(renderABC());
я знаю что можно сделать так ${renderABC().innerHTML}
но тогда блок созданный как обертка в функции пропадет, я про блок под переменной a

Comment: При желании возможно всё, но лучше сделать по-человечески...

Comment: Да можно сделать.... просто вопрос:  если вам нужна просто html строка, то зачем в функции `renderABC` вы делаете `createElement` ?  Делайте там сразу строку такого формата, которая необходима

Comment: @Qwertiy, подскажи как, если не сложно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, просто перебрал, что бы вручную не вписывать ключ значение, как лучше сделать в этом случае?

Comment: Что именно лучше сделать?  ............... *"просто перебрал, что бы вручную не вписывать ключ значение"* --- а причём тут перебор в цикле объекта и создание элемента через `createElement` ? Как это вообще взаимосвязано?